# Elasticsearch mongodb Cassandra for scalable architecture

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, cassandra, architecture

I'm designing a new system for a project wanted some suggestions from ground up.

1. Elasticsearch as primary datastore
2. Elasticsearch + cassandra
3. Elasticsearch + mongodb

   Which one is recommended ?

Req1: Zero tolerance on data loss
Req2: includes payment transaction + critical data

Datasize : 3 billion total data records / year
Retention :  N/a

Thanks
Shashi

Comment: Have you read the elastic store guidance on using it as a primary datastore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch and cassandra is a common design decission. You could take a look on elassandra project. We just migrated from bare cassandra and it works like a charm.